# Linux: Changing device names in /dev, causes problems on boot

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I have many disks and volumes in  my system. Some of disks IDE, some SATA.

Volumes on SATA disks cause me problems - I have them listed in `etc/fstab`, but on every boot, they have different name:

- `/dev/sdd*` becomes `/dev/sdb*`
- `/dev/sde*` becomes `/dev/sdc*`

etc. on every boot.

1) Why is this happening?
2) How can I prevent it?
3) If I can't, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 7):

It usually happens because devices get detected in a different order - especially when multiple different device technologies share the same name, such as SATA, SCSI and USB disks.  They all share the /dev/sd* names, and they will change according to what you have plugged in at the time.

There are a number of ways you can work around it.

1. Label the partitions then mount them by label
2. Mount them by UUID

From `man fstab`:

> Instead  of giving the device explicitly, one may indicate the (ext2 or
>          xfs) filesystem that is to be mounted by its UUID or volume label  (cf.
>          e2label(8)  or  xfs_admin(8)),  writing  LABEL=  or UUID=,
>          e.g.,  `LABEL=Boot'   or`UUID=3e6be9de-8139-11d1-9106-a43f08d823a6'.
>          This  will  make the system more robust: adding or removing a SCSI disk
>          changes the disk device name but not the filesystem volume label.

Labeling a disk can be done with (for example)

```
# tune2fs -L MyDiskLabel /dev/sde2
```

then use LABEL=MyDisklabel as the device name in /etc/fstab

Mounting can be done by using UUID= in /etc/fstab in place of the device name.

The UUID can be obtained by `blkid` (in Ubuntu at least - not sure about other distros)

Comment: `blkid` is part of `util-linux`, it should work on all Linux distributions.

Comment: On machines running `udev`, another method of accessing disks by label or UUID is through `/dev/disk/by-label/<label>` and `/dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID>`.

Answer (score 1):

*Not sure if posting a link to my blog is bad habit in here (I'm quite new around here) so my apologies if so.*

Last week I wrote a post about labeling with uuid several old reiserfs partitions so it may be of interest for the former poster to take a look at it.

http://hmontoliu.blogspot.com/2011/04/set-uuid-on-reiserfs-partitions-fun.html

Comment: As long as it's a) not commercial, and b) you say it's yours, that's fine.  In fact, if you like blogging, why not contribute to the Super User blog? ;)

Comment: I'll take it in to account :-)

Comment: actually, if you decide to contribute, you can include the relevant description/code here, in case one day you decide to change your blog address and the link becomes dead.